# Can you embed one video inside another?

Tags: video-editor

I'm quite new to video editing so I like some advice on whether it is possible to embed one video inside another?

The kind of effect I'm aiming for is to have one video playing then have it pause whilst another smaller video pops out (like a caption I guess) which plays then disappears leaving the original 'background' video to continue to completion.  The clips are reasonably short at around 2-5 mins.  They are in various formats avi, mpeg xvid - all commonly used, however I expect to have to convert them all to the same format in order to do this.

What editing software (for windows) would I be able to do this in, if indeed it is possible!!  I am reasonably technical but I don't want anything too over the top, unless of course I'm not going to do this with anything simple!!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is an editor with basic [picture-in-picture (PiP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture-in-picture) capabilities. For full and total control (including getting the "background" video to pause), I'd recommend [Adobe Premiere Pro](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere.html). A lot of simple editors (like iMovie, Windows Movie Maker, or even Adobe Premiere Elements) might allow for some **very basic** PiP, but usually nothing more than letting you put a second video in a corner.

Premiere Pro (or, better yet, any modern NLE of its caliber) will let you stack videos into "layers" on a single timeline, letting you place a "smaller" video "in front of" (or "on top of", from a *layers* standpoint) the full frame.

Comment: I use Adobe Premiere Pro and was going to offer this same answer. There's one thing I want to add:  Adobe Premiere is part of Adobe's "Creative Cloud" suite of programs. So if you see Creative Cloud, that's the version of Premiere you're looking for. (That confused me when I was researching different editing programs.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for this guys :)  I'll be having a look at Adobe Premier Pro. I assume it's relatively easy to do - I guess I'll see if I can get a trial download!!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "pops out like a caption",

If you mean something that is completly "pre-programmed" then that is simply a matter of editing the video with the kind of visual effects that implement your desired effect.

If you mean something that is dependent on the view interaction (clicking on something, for example), then that depends on how you are PLAYING it for the viewer.  You would need to embed the video in a web page (or equivalent) where you could sense viewer interaction (clicking, mouse-over, etc.).

Not possible to really answer your question properly without a better concept of what you are trying to do here.